# Google ngx_pagespeed: Rewriting JPG urls for CDN

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

I have CloundFront as image CDN and all my pages are static HTML. I have all the new image urls DomainMapped to `xxxxxx.cloudfront.net` address but for all previously uploaded images to my website url. I know you can redirect all the images through Nginx with location rewrite but since PageSpeed is already rewriting the URLS for the CDNs I was wondering is there configuration in PageSpeed for rewriting all the JPEG in my server to cloudfront.net address.

Example.

```
http://www.website.com/images/someimg.jpg
```

To.

```
http://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/images/someimg.jpg
```

Comment: Did you tried https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains#mapping_rewrite